# How to apply tf.image.per_image_standardization() to a tensor with the wrong shape?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor of 10.000 pictures in 32x32x3 format. So the Tensor is D4 (shape (10000,32,32,3).

```
Tensor("...", shape=(10000, 32, 32, 3), dtype=float32)
```

Now i want to apply the `tf.image.per_image_standardization` operations to the individual images:

```
tf. image. per_image_standardization (...)
```

What is the best practice in this case? Maybe slice the tensor in 10000 tensors with the shape (32,32,3)?

Comment: So your problem is that you have `(10000, 3, 32, 32)` but the function requires `(10000, 32, 32, 3)`? If that is the case use [tf.transpose](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose). 
 It should be something like this `tf.transpose(image, perm=[0,2,3,1])`

Comment: The problem is that i want to apply the 4. operation (tf. image. per_image_standardization (...)) at all 10000 images individual. So i want 10000x tf. image. per_image_standardization (...) on a shape of (32, 32, 3). sorry i edit the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.map_fn` for applying a specified function to every element of a tensor (unrolling it from the first dimension):

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.get_variable("a", (10000,32,32,3))
a = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.image.per_image_standardization(x), a, parallel_iterations=10000)
print(a.shape)
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Dear @nessuno, thank you very much. What if I have a tensor with shape (1000, 2, 40, 40, 40) and I want to apply the standardization to only one of the two (40,40,40) with an if condition? Is it possible to perform a nested tf.map_fn?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it should work without any problem. map_fn can be nested, in the end you're unrolling a tensor, thus, if you nest 2 map fn (the first one unroll the 1000, the second one unrell the 2), you can use a tf.cond node inside the second-one and do what you need